# Выборочная минификация SVG спрайта

Tags: css, svg, svg-спрайт

Не так давно работаю с SVG спрайтами и в целом все устраивало. Запускался task в gulp, создавался svg спрайт и scss файл с величинами иконок. Все это добавлялось в разметку и величины цвета и размеры комфортно менялись через css.

Все иконки были одноцветные.

Недавно стали попадаться иконки с несколькими цветами. Например:

```
<symbol viewBox="0 0 43.922 41.992" id="microsoft-logo"><path d="M20.874 19.953H0V0h20.874v19.953zM43.922 19.953H23.049V0h20.873v19.953zM20.873 41.992H0V22.04h20.873v19.952zM43.922 41.992H23.049V22.04h20.873v19.952z"/></symbol>
```

Разумеется npm пакет удаляет все fill и объединяет все path в один. И, разумеется, иконка становится одноцветной.

```
<symbol viewBox="0 0 43.922 41.992" id="microsoft-logo"><path d="M20.874 19.953H0V0h20.874v19.953zM43.922 19.953H23.049V0h20.873v19.953zM20.873 41.992H0V22.04h20.873v19.952zM43.922 41.992H23.049V22.04h20.873v19.952z"/></symbol>
```

Какие есть пути решения данной проблемы? Конечно можно вставить потом в спрайт верхнюю строчку со всеми цветами ручками, но это уже не автоматизация.
Уверен, что такая проблема уже встречалась. Буду рад помощи)

**P.S.** использую svgmin, svgsprite и cheerio(он и удаляет лишние поля).